# Send response from REST to JSP after @POST

Tags: java, rest, jsp

I have a JSP page (client-side)

```
<form action="http://localhost:8080/REST-WS/rest/token" method="POST">
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input name="email" />
<br/>
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input name="password" />
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

It points to a function in REST Web Service (server-side)

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Code verify(@FormParam("email") String email,
@FormParam("password") String password,
@Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws IOException {
    Code code = generateRandomCode(email,password);
    return token;
}
```

The problem is I want to give response to the client side containing the random-generated code from the server side.

First, it will be redirected to another JSP page and then the client side can receive the random-generated code from server.

How do I do it?

Comment: What JAX-RS implementation (and version) are you using?

Comment: I use this tutorial for the server side http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html#crud

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you can't send arbitrary Java objects in a redirect. You *can* however add the data into query parameters. For example

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response post(@FormParam("name") String name,
                     @FormParam("email") String email) {
    
    String message = "Hello " + name + ". Your email is " + email;
    URI uri = UriBuilder.fromPath("/index.jsp")
            .queryParam("message", message)
            .build();
    return Response.seeOther(uri).build();
}
```

Here, you are building a URI from the location of the jsp page, and adding a query parameter to the end of the URI. So the redirect will go to

```
http://localhost:8080/index.jsp?message=<the message>
```

From the `index.jsp` page you can get the parameter with `request.getParameter("message")`. For example

```
<h1><%= request.getParameter("message") %></h1>
```

Another option to work with JSP and Jersey is to implement MVC, which Jersey provides support for. You can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31900846/2587435), though the examples use Maven (to get all the required jars). If you are interested and don't know how to use Maven, let me know and I'll see if I can help you get all the jars you need.

---

### UPDATE

#### Ajax Example.

Easiest Javascript library to get started with (if you have no experience) is [jQuery](https://jquery.com/). I won't really give much explanation about the code, that's kinda out of scope. I would go through some tutorials (W3Schools has some good getting started guides), and there are answers all over SO that can answer your questions.

Here's a complete working html page. Just change `var url = "/api/submit";` to whatever endpoint you are sending the request to.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ajax Example</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var url = "/api/submit";
                
                $("#submitBtn").click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    
                    var formData = $("#nameForm").serialize();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        data: formData,
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function(data) {
                            var message = data.message;
                            var date = data.date;
                            
                            var h1 = $("<h1>").text(message);
                            var h3 = $("<h3>").text(date);
                            
                            $("#content").empty()
                                    .append(h1).append(h3);
                        },
                        error: function(jqxhr, status, errorMsg) {
                            alert(status + ": " + errorMsg);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <form id="nameForm">
                First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"/><br/>
                Last Name : <input type="text" name="lname"/><br/>
                <button id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the test resource class

```
@Path("submit")
public class FormResource {
    
    public static class Model {
        public String message;
        public String date;
    }
    
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public Model post(@FormParam("fname") String fname,
                      @FormParam("lname") String lname) {

        String message = "Hello " + fname + " " + lname;
        Model model = new Model();
        model.message = message;
        model.date = new Date().toString();
        return model;
    }
}
```

You will need to make sure you have a JSON provider to handle the JSON Pojo serialization or it won't work (the `Model` won't be able to serizalize to JSON).

Comment: How to use XML or JSON instead of parameter? Is it possible?

Comment: Redirects don't have any body. If you want to make an ajax request instead, it can return JSON to the calling page. Or you can return a jsp page without a redirect. For that you should look into the MVC

Comment: The problem is in the application I'm currently working on, server (REST) and client(JSP) have to be on different ports, so I don't think MVC work. But I'm intersted with your solution to make an ajax request. Can you give me an example?

Comment: I got this error `SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json`

Comment: Exactly. I said you need a JSON provider. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32412830/2587435)